# When an object is returned from a method, is a new instance or a reference created?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do methods which return Reference Types return references or cloned copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950889/do-methods-which-return-reference-types-return-references-or-cloned-copy)

A co-worker of mine stated that when a method returns an object like the following, a new instance/copy of the object is created as opposed to passing back a reference:

```
public CustomerEntity Customer { get; set; }

public CustomerEntity GetCustomer() {
    Customer = new CustomerEntity();
    return Customer;    
}
```

Is that correct?  My tests seem to indicate otherwise, but I am not certain how to confirm this.  He is concerned about the overhead in copying data to the new object.

For good measure, in which of the following methods/scenarios are new objects created?  In which situations does the calling class access a reference to or a copy of the to the original object?  Assume the 'CustomerEntity' is a very large object.

```
public class CustMan {
public CustomerEntity GetCustomer() {
    Customer = new CustomerEntity();
    return Customer
}

public void FillCustomer(CustomerEntity customer)
{
    customer = new CustomerEntity();
    // Calling class: 
    // CustomerEntity ce = new CustomerEntity(); 
    // l_custMan.FillCustomer(ce);  WriteLine(ce.Name);   
}

public void LoadCustomer()
{
    Customer = new CustomerEntity();
    // Calling Class access customerEntity via l_custMan.CustomerEntity
}
}
```

Clarification:  My co-worker believes it would be better to use a 'Load' method than a 'Get' method:

```
l_custMan.Load();
CustomerEntity = l_custMan.Customer;
```

vs.

```
CustomerEntity = l_custMan.GetCustomer();
```

Comment: Your co-worker is wrong. It's just a reference being returned (albeit a copy of the reference.) He's confusing this situation with a value type, which *would* be completely copied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> A co-worker of mine stated that when a method returns an object like the following, a new instance/copy of the object is created as opposed to passing back a reference:

Your coworker is incorrect<sup>*</sup>. For return types that are reference types, a copy is always made, it's just that it is a copy of the reference that is made.

I can be a bit more explicit:

Assuming that `ReturnType` is a reference type and given

```
public ReturnType M() {
    // some code
    return E;
}
```

where `E` is an expression that evaluates to an instance `I` of `ReturnType`, you are asking if a copy `C` of `I` is made and a reference to `C` is returned to the caller, or if a reference to `I` is returned to the caller. The answer is that a reference to `I` is returned to the caller.

This is the same for parameters of reference type passed into methods (unless they are marked with `ref` or `out`): a copy is always made, it is just a copy of the reference that is passed.

<sup>*</sup>: In his defense, he's possibly getting confused by some knowledge of C++, where you have to be explicit that you are returning a reference.

Comment: +1: Much better summation of the situation than my tired rambly mumblings :)

Comment: I like to use the terminology "an object reference is returned by value" (or, for parameters, "an object reference is passed by value").  I'd prefer to call the things stored in class-type variables as "instance ids" rather than "object references", so as not to overload the term "reference" (which could also refer to the thing passed in a ref parameter), and to make clear what's going on.  If a worker at an automotive body shop received a work order that said "Paint car #1G574X8 blue", the worker would know...

Comment: ...to look for a car with the specified VIN and paint the car blue.  The worker would not be expected to return a slip of paper with the VIN inked over in blue ink, nor would he be expected to create a new car which was like the old one but was blue.  Passing a parameter to a function would be like copying the number onto a new work order; it would duplicate the number, but not the car.

Answer (score 0):

While only a reference is returned your method seems odd:

```
public CustomerEntity GetCustomer() {
    Customer = new CustomerEntity();
    return Customer;    
}
```

The name suggests that it returns a field, instead it creates a new object, overwrites a property and then returns a reference, so here an object *is* created every time.

The method should probably be this:

```
public CustomerEntity GetCustomer() {
    return Customer;    
}
```

But that is superfluous as your property already has a getter.

(*I assume `CustomerEntity` to be a class rather than a struct, for structs a copy is created*)

Comment: I see how the name is confusing. My intention is to look at the best way to Fill an object and use that object in the calling class.  The 'GetCustomer' method would create a new instance, fill from the Database, then return it to the calling object.

Answer (score -1):

You will be returning a reference to the object. To create a "new" copy, you will need to create a completely new entity.

```
public CustomerEntity GetCustomer() {
    CustomerEntity toReturn = new CustomerEntity();
    return toReturn ;    
}
```

Comment: What if `CustomerEntity` is a value type?

Comment: Well, then I guess that should be specified in the question. If CustomerEntity was a value type (which I highly doubt based on the op's description) then a copy will be made by a simple assignment.

Comment: It's still copying the reference to `toReturn` back to the caller. That's what the question is fundamentally asking.

Comment: I guess I am interpreting the question wrong then. I thought the OP is asking will a "new" or "reference to an existing" object be returned. The answer is: a reference to the existing object.

Comment: @tribe84: The question should be thought of as this: assuming that `ReturnType` is a reference type, given `public ReturnType M() { // some code; return returnType; }`. Is a copy of the referent of `returnType` made, and a reference to that returned, or is a reference to `returnType` returned?

Comment: Maybe the asker isn't aware of the distinction. Sorry, but a good SO answer shouldn't put any assumptions on the question.

Comment: Binary, you are right, I should not have made the assumption.